# Python SCPClient copy progress check

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm new on SCPClient Module

I have got copy samples as

```
 with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
    scp.put(source, destination)
```

This code works well.

However, since I'm copy several large files, copy progress will take time, blindly waiting till it done is not good user experience.

Is there anyway that I could monitor how much has it copied? And catch the result if copy is succeed or not?

And does SCPClient have official document to read?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you look at the [Github page?](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py) They provide an example of how to do this:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient
import sys

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('example.com')

# Define progress callback that prints the current percentage completed for the file
def progress(filename, size, sent):
    sys.stdout.write("%s\'s progress: %.2f%%   \r" % (filename, float(sent)/float(size)*100) )

# SCPCLient takes a paramiko transport and progress callback as its arguments.
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport(), progress = progress)

scp.put('test.txt', '~/test.txt')
# Should now be printing the current progress of your put function.

scp.close()
```

Comment: Hi, Eagle. What if I need check progress in every 3 sec? I tried to add sleep(3) in progress function, it slows down the copy progress.@eagle

Answer (score 1):

As Eagle answers, they are good to print out progress. However, the frequency of printing is too high, it will consume a lot resources.

To control the print frequency, we need override _send_file or _send_files function

```
def _send_files(self, files):
...
        buff_size = self.buff_size
        chan = self.channel
        # Add time control
        time_cursor=datetime.datetime.now()
        while file_pos < size:
            chan.sendall(file_hdl.read(buff_size))
            file_pos = file_hdl.tell()
            now=datetime.datetime.now()
            # Status check every one sec
            if self._progress and (now-time_cursor).seconds>1:
                self._progress(basename, size, file_pos)
                time_cursor=now
        chan.sendall('\x00')
        file_hdl.close()
        self._recv_confirm()
```