# Netmiko SecureCopy Progressbar

Tags: python, progress-bar, scp, netmiko

I am trying to improve my code and add the progressbar to the `file_transfer` function. I was wondering how can I calculate the `sent` argument? I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657776/python-scpclient-copy-progress-check/#answer-49657868) and this on [GitHub](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py), but I can't figure out how to use it with my provided code.

```py
from os.path import getsize

from netmiko import ConnectHandler, file_transfer, progress_bar

router = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "host": "sandbox-iosxe-latest-1.cisco.com",
    "username": "developer",
    "password": "C1sco12345",
    "port": 22,
    "verbose": True,
    "conn_timeout": 12,
    "fast_cli": False,
    "session_log": "sandbox-iosxe-latest-1.cisco.com.log",
}

src_file = dest_file = input("Name of file to copy: ")

with ConnectHandler(**router) as net_connect:
    scp = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands=["ip scp server enable"])
    transfer = file_transfer(
        net_connect,
        source_file=src_file,
        dest_file=dest_file,
        file_system="flash:",
        direction="put",
        overwrite_file=True,
        socket_timeout=100.0,
        progress=progress_bar(
            filename=src_file,
            size=getsize(src_file),
            sent=sent,  # How to calculate? What should be placed here?
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just be `progress=progress_bar` or `progress4=progress_bar`. You just provide a callable that is constructed a certain way (and you are using the progress_bar function that Netmiko provides so that should be fine).

Here is an example file_transfer using it:

```
ssh_conn = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
transfer_dict = file_transfer(
    ssh_conn,
    source_file=source_file,
    dest_file=dest_file,
    file_system=file_system,
    direction=direction,
    # Force an overwrite of the file if it already exists
    overwrite_file=True,
    progress4=progress_bar,
)
```